# Matlab image processing

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a folder which contains images (100) from the experiment that I did. I also have another folder which contains the background images (100 also) from the detector.

I have written a code that does something like this:

```
%  Define images directory
% Define detector bg directory


% Loop over each frame and do some processing

for a=1:length(image directory)

%read files from directory

bg_corrected_image = frame#-bg_image#    % # begins with 1 


n=size(image directory)
new_images=zeros(n)

% Now sort through each pixel in bg_corrected image and assign value according to a criterion

for  ii=1:size(bg_corrected_image,1)
     jj=1:size(bg_corrected_image,2)

      pixel=bg_corrected_image(ii,jj);

        if pixel>500
            pix_mod=0;

        elseif pixel<30
            pix_mod=0;
        else 
            pix_mod=pixel;
        end

        new_image(ii,jj)=pix_mod;
    end

******************* CODE TO SAVE IMAGE AND NOT OVERWRITE AFTER EACH 
ITERATION OF LOOP?

end
```

What I want to do now is to save each image(frame) after it had gone through the pixel sorting regimen so that I can just sum them all after the loop has ended. I am not too sure what is the best way to do it? I think what I need to do is to create a cell array which saves a "new_image" after each iteration and the code for that should go where I put asteriks. Please note I don't want to save images earlier in my code. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: you should try using vectorization instead of loops in matlab. You can use a function on matrix from the image processing that will replace the loops in one line (I haven't written matlab for years, so I apologize for not being specific)

Comment: Yes, I will vectorise the whole thing after I have figured out how to work my code in for loop first. Thanks.

Comment: Save as a 3D matrix - `new_images=zeros(n,n,numel(image directory))` and later on `new_image(ii,jj,a)=pix_mod;`. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. I was trying to create a 1d cell array to save one image at a time into elements (buckets). I will try something out and get back to you. thank.

Comment: @user3673737 Allow me to ask you - Why cell arrays?

Comment: sorry for the late reply; have a lot on my plate. I wanted to create a cell array so that I could use the images outside the loop for summing, but realised that one can do it inside the loop and that is what I did in the end and my code is working now. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the below - load in all your images to a 3D matrix "imagestack", then process them all, then output them all.  Note the vectorization on the pixel replacement here will be much faster than your for-loop iteration over the pixels.

```
IMAGECOUNT=100;
FILEPATH_IN='images/input/%d.jpg';
FILEPATH_OUT='images/output/%d.jpg';

I=imread(sprintf(FILEPATH,1));
[hei wid]=size(I);

imagestack=zeros(hei,wid,100);

for n=1:IMAGECOUNT
    imagestack(:,:,n)=imread(sprintf(FILEPATH_IN,n)); 
end

imagestack(imagestack>500)=0;
imagestack(imagestack<30)=0;

for n=1:IMAGECOUNT
    imwrite(imagestack(:,:,n),sprintf(FILEPATH_OUT,n)); 
end
```